# Git, work on 2 branches, switch between them on local server

Tags: git, git-branch

Apologies for how basic this is..but remotely, I have a master branch and a dev branch I'm working on.  I check out the master like this:

```
git clone https://github...
```

and I can check out the dev branch like this:

```
git clone -b my-branch https://github...
```

Previously, I had both branches cloned locally in the same directory and i could see them listed with

```
git branch
```

I acheived this by building the dev branch locally and then pushing it to the server.  Then (to experiment) I deleted everything to see if I could recreate the setup whereby I have both the master and my dev branch in the same directory and I could switch between them.

Also, as I develop, I want to check what the dev branch looks like on my local server, and then switch to see what the master branch looks like on my localserver.  How is this problem normally solved please?  Do I need to have each branch in a seperate directory and start the server in that directory?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `git clone` twice into different locations, well, you don't really use branching the way it was intended.

You should `git clone` just once, and then you can `git checkout` to whatever branch you want. By default, after `git clone`, you will have just one local branch (probably `master`), but you can explore which branches are present on server by `git branch -av`. You can also checkout to server branch by `git checkout --track origin/another-branch` - this will create local tracking branch `another-branch`.

At any rate, you should really invest some time in reading good git book, for example [Progit](http://git-scm.com/book).

Comment: Ok, so I guess what I am trying to say is:  After cloning the master locally, I then want to bring in the branch i created which is on the remote server.  I want to switch to that branch and then view it on my localserver.  Currently, i clone the master and then try checkout the branch but it just creates it locally and doesn't seem to pull any new files in..

Comment: `git branch -av` will show all server branches, including what you created before (on server). Then `git checkout --track origin/that-branch` will create local branch that tracks server branch with the same name and make it active

Comment: That works but what i don't understand is that since the master is different to the branch i orignally cloned, why when doing 'checkout --track origin/that-branch' do i not get any new files?  And how therefore will this enable me to switch between the branch and master on my local server to view changes?

Comment: After you created tracking branches, they are now local, and you can switch between them using `git checkout branch-name` (`--track` only works once to create).

Comment: ok, all working now.  I can do a checkout to switch branch, restart the server, view changes, and then another checkout restart and see the other branch.  I suppose that's how it's supposed to work?  Thanks for your time, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: yes. when you need to get changes from the server, I suggest to use `git pull --rebase`. Try not to use naked `git pull` - it may create unwanted merge commits if you have some pending local commits

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get you right :) But If you cloned some repo you got it as **master** branch. Then if you wanted to have the same repo as another branch you didn't have to clone it seperatly :) all you needed to do is to do:

```
git checkout -b branch_name
```

and it would branch your master. Then you could push either your **master** or **branch_name** to REMOTE branch **master** or create new remote branch **branch_name** and i think this is what you wanted. But there is another way with cloning into a branch, which is usefull if you want to clone let us say REMOTE branch A to your LOCAL branch B, that means if you want to cross them :) But to answer your question if you didn't push your branch to remote repo it disappeared unfortunately. I will recomend that you read some documentation: http://git-scm.com/documentation about branching and checking out it really helps to get the idea of git.